# How to initialize inner ArrayList of a two-dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The below ArrayList is a two-dimensional ArrayList of size parts. I'm divding the storeIds into parts of ArrayList and add them to the inner ArrayList of the 2D ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partStoreIds = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(parts);    
for(int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Executing part: " + i);
        int maxIndex = Math.min(storeIds.size(), querySize*(i+1));
        //The below line is throwing an exception
        partStoreIds.addAll(storeIds.subList(querySize*i, maxIndex));           

    }
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Also, which type does `storeIds` have?

Comment: what's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Sorry about that @Turing85. storeIds is of type List<String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to achieve can be done as next:

```
partStoreIds.add(new ArrayList<>(storeIds.subList(querySize*i, maxIndex)));
```

Indeed, as `partStoreIds` is an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` only `ArrayList` instances can be added and since `storeIds.subList(querySize*i, maxIndex)` returns a `List`, you need to convert it first as an `ArrayList` using the constructor [`new ArrayList(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-).

But a much simpler approach would be to declare your `partStoreIds` as a `List` of `List`, then you can add your `subList` directly as next:

```
List<List<String>> partStoreIds = new ArrayList<>(parts);
...
    partStoreIds.add(storeIds.subList(querySize*i, maxIndex));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new `ArraraList` and then add items to it

```
ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();
temp.addAll(storeIds.subList(querySize*i, maxIndex));
partStoreIds.add(temp);
```

Comment: Some explanation would be beneficial.